# How To Solve Gradle Build Failed Error -Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Firebase Auth. I am working in unity 2018. I have dowloaded  Quickstart-unity-Master. In that I am working Auth Section. I have download the latest googlservices.json file also, but when I try to build the Firebase auth in android, it shows the error

Gradle build Error.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FXQm.png)

I have searched in Forum it Says  Java greater 8 is not supported. I am using  jdk1.8.0_171.

I  have donwloaded varrious unity packages 2017 Versions.

I Installed 10 Different versions. In that one versions First time it builds and apk produced. But second time I build it shows the error. Gradle Build failed.

How can I solve the gradle Error.

Thanks and Regads

Comment: Gradle build Error can be anything really, can you share the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

This error might not be related to Firebase at all. I have multiple projects where Gradle fails for some reason. Just try what happens when you switch the build system from Gradle to `Internal`. This works for my projects.

Comment: Thanks Hexodus for your reply.I also try internal option. But  different errors are displaying. I will Post the error Soon...